# getting force close when using findviewbyId()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm starting to learn android app development and currently practicing with simple apps. I'm writing this app that includes a listview and i want to fill it with fake data but, when i use `findViewbyId()` in my code the app gives me force close **BUT** when i set the content view to my fragment instead of activity_main i get no force close, but the app shows me an empty list.

This is my code :

```
package com.example.karen.please;

public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;
public MainActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String[] forecastArray =
            {
                    "sunny",
                    "cloudy",
                    "asteroids",
                    "rainy",
                    "sunny"
            };
    List<String> weekforecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));
    mForecastAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity(),
                    R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                    R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                    weekforecast
            );
    ListView mylistview = (ListView)container.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);   //screws upp in this line
    mylistview.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, true);
}}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: post your logcat, plase. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to find a view before you inflate your layout...  Try inflating at the top of your method, like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, true);

    <all the other init code you have>

    return myView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using `findViewById` you should Create a `View` variable, use the `inflate..` line, use `findViewById` on the `View` variable you created, and then return that.

This is what your code should look like:

```
package com.example.karen.please;
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;
public MainActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Instead of inflate and return instantly, store it in a variable,
    // Then return at the end of the method.
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, true);

    [...]

    // Here, use findViewById on the View you have just inflated.
    ListView mylistview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);   //screws upp in this line
    mylistview.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);
    // Return the view you created on the beginning.
    return view;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need inflate your layout...

```
           @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            ...
            ListView  mylistview = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);    
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start with a proper tutorial not chaotically adding code that you don't understand. Start reading here:
[Creating and Using Fragments](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-and-Using-Fragments) 
After you understood how it goes then you will see that first you need to inflate the layout that contains the stuff you want to find by id and then by using the view(that defines the layout) you can find the desired view(listview, etc).

Answer (score -1):

```
ListView  my listview = (ListView).findViewById(R.id.listview_forcast);
```

I think this is how it should be, no container in the code

Comment: The `findViewById` function without any view specified before works only in Activities. In cases like this, when using a Fragment, you have to get a view using `getView()` or some other `View` variable, and call `findViewById` on that view. Something like `view.findViewById(R...)`, since they don't have a content view specified. Your answer works well for activities because you use `setContentView(R.layout..)` after creating each of them, so you have a view "bound" to the Activity.

Comment: I can see what your saying, and how you did it. Your answer wasn't up there when I submitted mine. I haven't dealt with fragments, only full activities like you said. Thanks for the extra explanation, I'll be looking for this answer in a couple weeks lol.

Comment: No problem! I have seen that someone downvoted it but left no comment, unfortunately that's common here. I was trying to explain it to you because i've had many doubts about it in the past and took a while to understand it. So maybe i could help someone else :)